# Error in Trigger for incrementing the value with Prefix and Integer.

Tags: mysql, triggers

Here i am using Trigger to Auto Increment the field 'Project_Id' with Prefixed String.
First I am Retrieving the last Record and Store into the variable.After that sub-string of that record was stored into another variable and then converted into the Integer.

```
delimiter //
     CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_project_master
     BEFORE INSERT ON project_master
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     DECLARE selectid VARCHAR(20);
     DECLARE selid VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE autoi INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET selectid := (select Project_id from project_master order by Project_id desc limit 1);
    SET selid := SUBSTRING_INDEX(selectid,'O',-1);
    SET autoi := 1+ CAST(@selectid AS INT);
    INSERT INTO project_master SET NEW.Project_id = CONCAT('PRJ',@autoi);
END; //
DELIMITER;
```

After Incrementing the value with 1 I am inserting back into the Table(Project_master).

This is the Error i am getting.

> Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER tg_project_master
>   BEFORE INSERT ON project_master
>   FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   DEC' at line 1
>   Line 2, column 1

Comment: `INSERT INTO project_master SET ...`? Shouldn't this be an  `UPDATE`

Comment: No, I am inserting this value before any other data of that record entered

Comment: I see and didn't know about this notation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 delimiter //
 CREATE TRIGGER tg_project_master
 BEFORE INSERT ON project_master
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     DECLARE selectid INT DEFAULT 0;
     SET selectid := (select CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Project_id,'O',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num  from project_master order by Project_id desc limit 1);
     SET selectid := selectid + 1;
     SET NEW.Project_id = CONCAT('PRO',selectid);
END; //
DELIMITER;
```

The Problem was that i was using the @ sign when it wasn't needed and using CAST() instead of Convert() Function. 
Now, my Auto incremented Prefixed Id is inserted when i insert a new record as following format.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) you can't `CREATE OR REPLACE` a trigger, but only `CREATE` it. So do the following:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tg_project_master;

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER tg_project_master
  BEFORE INSERT ON project_master
  FOR EACH ROW
  ....
END; //
DELIMITER;
```